# No input file specified

Tags: ee2

Nuts nuts...

www.example.com works, but when accessing www.example.com/index.php/template_group, or any other pages, EE gives No input file specified-message and nothing therefore works.
Version 2.5.3 with Channel Images, likEE, Wygwam...

but what makes this very very odd, is that the site worked just fine 3 months ago when i was working on it. Now its dead end.

What might be the issue?

EDIT: Was a serverside issue, host made updates on server, so therefore stopped from working. I got email from them and check all later today, but did try fastlink to one i remember, and it worked as before - so i think they fixed their own hassle :)

Comment: Is this an upgraded installation or clean install? Do you have a .htaccess file? If so, what's in it? Can you access the templates in your default template group (the one marked with the pink asterisk in template manager)?

Comment: Have you checked or run through any of the troubleshooting suggestions from the documentation (which sites no input file specified): http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer below and accept your answer as the correct one by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer after submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a serverside issue, host made updates on server, so therefore stopped from working.

Answer (score 2):

Pete, have you tried adding a question mark to your URLs? ie: example.com/index.php?/template_group?

Try that, if it works, you need to add the question mark to your index.php or set Force Query Strings to "Yes" in Admin > Output and Debugging.

Comment: this was going to be my answer as well.